# Adding labor cost as the model simulates on AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I created a variable, called labour cost. And I want this to increase, for example by 40 every 900s that the simulation is run. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Add an event with the following properties:

[image]

Instead of variable, use the name of your total cost variable of course.

Answer (score 0):

Anything can be done with AnyLogic ;)

Use a recurring event that triggers this code every 900s:

```
myVariable+=40;
```

This is very basic so I also suggest you dig into all step-by-step tutorials that come with the help :)

Comment: Hi @Berbatov please flag useful answers using the "up" arrow next to the answers ;)